# Suppose every family makes babies until a boy is born: will this result in gender bias in the society?

Tags: probability

Suppose in a society where every family wants a boy in their family at least: The family give births to children until the first boy is born. As soon as the first boy is born, they stop making babies.

Will such practice result in the society having more males than females?

what if I change the question to "every family stops making baby as soon as two boys are born"?

Comment: Is this a homework question.  This question needs an assumption that boys and girls are independent Bernoulli trials with equal probability for boys and girls.  One of the most useful approaches to understanding this question is to start with $2^n$ families and imagine them perfectly splitting boys and girls at each "round" of babies.  This should give you a lot of intuition.

Comment: I've done an answer but won't post it until we know if this is homework or not (in which case I'll turn it into hints).

Comment: This one is even fairly easy to program. It took me around 30 lines, including empty lines. Sometimes such self programmed experiments by using random data generators help to oversee the situation and have a guess for the answer.

Comment: thx for the comments and this is not a homework question at all... I like to randomly think of such questions related to probability and have posted some questions like this in the past.